# How to specify the CFLAGS to gcc-4.6 or gcc-4.7 to use the Intel-AVX

Tags: gcc, intel, avx

I have an Intel Core i7-3770, and I found that it contains the AVX, How do I specify the CFLAGS to gcc-4.6 or gcc-4.7 to use the Intel-AVX? Is there some example code or manual about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `-mavx` switch or select proper CPU using `-march=flag` with flag equal `corei7-avx`, `core-avx-i` or `core-avx2`.

Still the compiler may not generate vectorized code unless you add some other switches.